# How can I gzip json returned from a JsonResult action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, iis-7, gzip

I do have gzip set up correctly on my IIS 7.5 web server, and it works in most cases.

But I can see that the response headers show that any requests that I make to a JsonResult method are not gzipped.  What do I need to change so that JsonResult returns data with Content-Encoding: gzip?

This is a screenshot of headers when calling a JsonResult method:

[image]

As compared to a screenshot of headers when calling something that returns html, eg RenderPartial():

[image]

EDIT: These are my compression settings from applicationHost.config:

```
    <httpCompression 
        directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />                
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />                
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

Comment: If you change <add mimeType="*/*"> to enabled=true, does the JSON get compressed? This post mentions debugging that scenario (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/02/19/unable-to-compress-json-result-in-iis-7-x.aspx)

Comment: What are your urlCompression settings from your applicationHost.config and your web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your IIS applicationHost.config file located at **%WinDir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config** contains following code block.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />       
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, those settings were already set to TRUE.  I've updated the question with my compression settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks correct.  It could be you have not reached the threshold for IIS to start compressing everything.

Try this:
In IIS Manager, go to the Configuration Editor, and find system.WebServer/serverRuntime.
Look at the frequentHitThreshold and the frequentHitTimePeriod settings, and and drop those down to guarantee that you meet the threshold when you are testing.

Here's more reading:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/02/19/unable-to-compress-json-result-in-iis-7-x.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I tried setting `frequentHitThreshold=1` but that still didn't help.